# Extra table created in JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

im using an intermediator table to show the relation between ingredient and taco which has manyToMany relation type.
this is ingredient class

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED,force = true)
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private final Type type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient")
    private List<IngredientRef> ingredientRefs = new ArrayList<>();


    public enum Type {
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }
```

this is my taco class

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Taco {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Date createdAt = new Date();

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany //list i need because i have methods using it
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ingredient") //list i made for intermediator class map
    private List<IngredientRef> ingredientRefs = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne //ignore this list
    @JoinColumn(name = "taco_order_id")
    private TacoOrder tacoOrder;
}
```

this is ingredientRef class

```
@Data
@Entity
public class IngredientRef {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
    private Ingredient ingredient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "taco_id")
    private Taco taco;
}
```

so the manyToMany table in Taco class which stores ingredient makes an extra table.I could have used it to make Ingredient_ref table using @JoinTable but i wanted extra column fields so i made a new entity.
any fix to not make that list an extra table while i could still use?
tldr; i need 3 tables (Taco Ingredient Ingredient_ref) while having the extra list in my taco class.

Answer (score 1):

Do a quick code review for you and have a following comments :

1. `mappedBy` in `Taco` is configured wrong. It should be :

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "taco") 
private List<IngredientRef> ingredientRefs = new ArrayList<>();
```

2. `ingredient_id` column in the `ingredient_ref` table cannot be the PK. If yes , you will make Ingredient and Taco as 1-to-many. So remove `@Id` from the `ingredient` field of `IngredientRef`.
3. To get rid of `List<Ingredient> ingredients` field in the `Ingredient` after the changes , you get the Ingredient list by calling instead :

```java
this.ingredientRefs.getIngredients();
```

Comment: im sorry for the first two i already looked and changed that,that was my bad. 
using ingredientRef list to get ingredient list would work but id have to change many other things. in my controller when i make a taco on webpage, the model sends the ids of the ingredients selected as post form request and it used a converter class to convert them to ingredients and then spring auto maps it to the ingredient list in Taco and sends a taco object to me so id have to change if im gonna remove that list no?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid creating an extra table for the `@ManyToMany` relationship between **Taco** and **Ingredient**, but still maintain a bidirectional relationship and have the ability to access the ingredients for a taco using a list, you can achieve this without creating a separate entity like **IngredientRef**. Instead, you can use a `@JoinTable` annotation with additional columns to represent the relationship between **Taco** and **Ingredient**.

Here is the code snippet shown below

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "taco_ingredient",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "taco_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id")
)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@MapKey(name = "type")
private Map<Ingredient.Type, Ingredient> ingredients = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: yes i did that only, i asked this question as before i needed this table to have 1 more id column so i had to create a new Entity and thus this question